# Setting up a Home Network with an Attic?

Tags: networking

So I'm looking to set up a wired home network, and honestly I've never done it before. I have a decent knowledge with most hardware things but networking is my weak point.

Right now I have cable running into a few bedrooms, and I just have a normal Motorola Surfboard Modem and old Asus router sitting in the office, however we have a massive amount of wireless devices so I'm looking to go ahead and upgrade our network devices while I do this.

The problem however to me is: I have a One story with a loft. I imagine the actual coax cable goes from the box outside an up into the attic and then down into all the walls. Ideally I'd like to have an Ethernet port upstairs and then a port running down into my office closet (Where the hardware will go).

Is there a better way to do this? I mean I suppose I could put the equipment in the attic, but it gets VERY hot in the attic obviously, so it'd be tough on the equipment. The upstairs is mostly wireless so it doesn't 100% need a port, but I'd like to be able to wire it up to a switch of some sort.

What's the best solution to this? Apologies if this is the wrong sub-exchange to ask this.

Secondly: Cable from the ISP....where does that usually "go"....I'd assume up in the attic? Is there something I can put up there to split it or?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using powerline adaptors ?
I have used them where I want a wired link to odd places (like the attic) and they work very well.
So you use one lan port on your router to the base adaptor and then you can plug other adapters in anywhere and they will pick up wired signal. Some even have wifi built in so you can have a few extra wifi spots around the house.
Not sure if I'm allowed give a particular manufacturer that I use... but if you search for powerline adapters you will see all the popular makes.

The termination point of your broadband will depend I guess on who your provider is and whether they are using cable / dsl phone lines etc.

regards.